# Clojure Parse String

Tags: regex, clojure

I have the following string

```
layout: default
title: Envy Labs
```

What i am trying to do is create map from it

```
layout->default 
title->"envy labs"
```

Is this possible to do using sequence functions or do i have to loop through each line?

Trying to get a regex to work with and failing using.

```
(apply hash-map (re-split #": " meta-info))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
user> (let [x "layout: default\ntitle: Envy Labs"]
        (reduce (fn [h [_ k v]] (assoc h k v))
                {}
                (re-seq #"([^:]+): (.+)(\n|$)" x)))
{"title" "Envy Labs", "layout" "default"}
```

Comment: thx that worked, but i have one questions, (fn [h [_ k v]] what does _ mean do you skip everything but the last two params? or is it just a unused var name?

Comment: `_` is a normal variable name.  It's just a convention to say to human readers that it's a placeholder and you don't plan to use that variable.

Answer (score 3):

The _ is a variable name used to indicate that you don't care about the value of the variable (in this case, the whole matched string).

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend using [clojure-contrib/duck-streams/read-lines](http://richhickey.github.com/clojure-contrib/duck-streams-api.html#duck-streams/read-lines) to process the lines then split the fields from there. I find this method is usually more robust to errors in the file.